# How to List RingCentral Greetings?

Tags: ringcentral

Is there a way to get a list of greetings? I got a "Method Not Allowed" response trying to call this endpoint. Is this another one of those endpoints where you need to be registered in the Beta program?

`GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/greeting`

I want to use these ids to update greetings using the `POST` API:

`POST /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/greeting/{greetingId}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greetings are associated specific answering rule and you cannot reuse them so there's no real reason to get a list of greetings. That being said, you can enumerate the greetings in your system by calling the Answering Rule API.

**Enumeration**

You can view your greetings by calling the API for your answering rule. This example shows 1 custom greeting with a set of default greetings.

`GET /restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/answering-rule/{answeringRuleId}`

The response will have a set of greetings as show in the excerpt below:

```
{
    "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/extension/22222222/answering-rule/business-hours-rule",
    "id": "business-hours-rule",
    "type": "BusinessHours",
    "enabled": true,
    "schedule": {
        "ref": "BusinessHours"
    },
    "greetings": [
        {
            "type": "Voicemail",
            "custom": {
                "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/extension/22222222/greeting/33333333",
                "id": "33333333"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Introductory",
            "preset": {
                "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/greeting/66301",
                "id": "66301",
                "name": "None"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "ConnectingAudio",
            "preset": {
                "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/greeting/66310",
                "id": "66310",
                "name": "Acoustic"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "ConnectingMessage",
            "preset": {
                "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/greeting/68867",
                "id": "68867",
                "name": "Default"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "HoldMusic",
            "preset": {
                "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/greeting/197382",
                "id": "197382",
                "name": "Acoustic"
            }
        }
    ],
```

You can get a list of your `answeringRuleId` values by calling the `answering-rule` endpoint. This will include both your `business-hours-rule` and `after-hours-rule` ids as well as your custom answering rules:

`GET /restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/answering-rule`

**Deletion**

Greetings cannot be reused and are deleted from the system as long as they are no longer referenced. You can do this by either updating the rule with a different greeting or deleting the rule.